# Erro: Notice: Undefined index || PHP || MYSQL ||

Tags: php, mysql

Olá estou a desenvolver um filtro para uma loja online e estou a receber este erro quando inicio a pagina,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando clico no botão continuar do formulário, desaparecem todos excepto este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Aqui está o código do formulário:

```html
<div class="card-body"> 
<form method="post"> 
Referencia: 
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search" name="referencia"style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome"> 
<br><br> 
<div class="row"> 
Diametro do Aço (d): 
<div class="col-md-4"> 
<input type="text" name="d1" size="6" placeholder="min"> 
<input type="text" name="d2" size="6" placeholder="max"> 
</div> 
Comprimento total (L0): 
<div class="col-md-4"> 
<input type="text" name="comp1" size="6" placeholder="min"> 
<input type="text" name="comp2" size="6" placeholder="max"> 
</div> 
</div> 
<br> 
<div class="row"> 
Diametro Exterior (DE):
<div class="col-md-4"> 
<input type="text" name="de1" size="6" placeholder="min"> 
<input type="text" name="de2" size="6" placeholder="max"> 
</div> 
<br> 
</div>
<br> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Ordenar por:</label> 
<select class="form-control" name="ordenar" id="ordenar"> 
<option value="referencia">Referencia</option> 
<option value="diametroaco">Diametro do Aço (d)</option> 
<option value="comprimentototal">Comprimento total (L0)</option> 
<option value="diametroexterior">Diametro Exterior (DE)</option> 
<option value="passo">Passo (P)</option> 
</select> 
</div> 
<div class="col-md-9"> 
<div align="right"> 
<img src="imagens/desenho33.png" align="right" height="250" width="350" > 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<br> 
<div align="right"> 
<button type="reset" align="right" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button> 
<button type="submit" align="right" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Continuar</button> 
</div> 
</form>
```

Este é o codigo que está com os erros:

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){ 
    if ($_POST["d1"]<>""){
$d1=$_POST["d1"];
    }else{
        $d1="0,200";
    }
    if ($_POST["d2"]<>""){
$d2=$_POST["d2"];
    }else{
        $d2="20";
    }
    if ($_POST["comp1"]<>""){
$comp1=$_POST["comp1"];
    }else{
        $comp1="1";
    } 
    if ($_POST["comp2"]<>""){
$comp2=$_POST["comp2"];
    }else{
        $comp2="10000";
    } 
    if ($_POST["de1"]<>""){
$de1=$_POST["de1"];
    }else{
        $de1="1";
    }
    if ($_POST["de2"]<>""){
$de2=$_POST["de2"];
    }else{
        $de2="200";
    }  
}
$ordenar=$_POST["ordenar"]; 

//if(isset($_POST["getproduct"])){ 
//$ordenar="nome"; 
//} 
switch($ordenar){ 
case "referencia": 
$ordenar_por="order by referencia"; 
break; 
case "diametroaco": 
$ordenar_por="order by diametroaco"; 
break; 
case "comprimentototal": 
$ordenar_por="order by comprimentototal"; 
break; 
case "diametroexterior": 
$ordenar_por="order by diametroexterior"; 
break; 
case "passo": 
$ordenar_por="order by passo"; 
break; 
} 

include ("db.php"); 
// $molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp"; 
   //$molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp $ordenar_por"; 
$molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp WHERE (diametroaco BETWEEN '$d1' and '$d2') AND (comprimentototal BETWEEN '$comp1' AND '$comp2') AND (diametroexterior BETWEEN '$de1' AND '$de2') $ordenar_por"; 

$run_query = mysqli_query($con,$molcomp_query); 
         var_dump($run_query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){ 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){ 
$id_mol_comp=$row['id_mol_comp']; 
$referencia=$row['referencia']; 
$diametroaco=$row['diametroaco']; 
$comprimentototal=$row['comprimentototal']; 
$diametroexterior=$row['diametroexterior']; 
$passo=$row['passo']; 
$preco=$row['preco']; 
echo" 
<div class='card mx-auto w-100'> 
<div class='card-body'> 
<div class='row'> 
<div class='col-md-1'>$referencia</div> 
<div class='col-md-2'>$diametroaco</div> 
<div class='col-md-2'>$comprimentototal</div> 
<div class='col-md-2'>$diametroexterior</div> 
<div class='col-md-1'>$passo</div> 
<div class='col-md-1'>$preco</div> 
<div class='col-md-1'><i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf1c1;</i> <i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf217;</i> </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<br>"; 
} 
}    
?>
```

Comment: Quando você inicia a página, não existe o post então não entre nesse `if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){ ` e dá o erro de variáveis indefinidas, esse erro provavelmente faz com que `$run_query` falhe e ao usar ele como parâmetro para `mysqli_num_rows` causa outro erro. Para ter certeza de um `var_dump($_POST)` antes da linha 217 e veja se as variáveis estão lá

Comment: sim, exatamente isso: o array aparece vazio: 
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Já resolveu o problema? Se não, retire o if ou coloque tudo dentro dele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um problema de fechamento no lugar errado, todo código deveria estar dentro da verificação do `if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST))`:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){
        if ($_POST["d1"]<>""){
            $d1=$_POST["d1"];
        }else{
            $d1="0,200";
        }
        if ($_POST["d2"]<>""){
            $d2=$_POST["d2"];
        }else{
            $d2="20";
        }
        if ($_POST["comp1"]<>""){
            $comp1=$_POST["comp1"];
        }else{
            $comp1="1";
        }
        if ($_POST["comp2"]<>""){
            $comp2=$_POST["comp2"];
        }else{
            $comp2="10000";
        }
        if ($_POST["de1"]<>""){
            $de1=$_POST["de1"];
        }else{
            $de1="1";
        }
        if ($_POST["de2"]<>""){
            $de2=$_POST["de2"];
        }else{
            $de2="200";
        } 

        $ordenar=$_POST["ordenar"];

        //if(isset($_POST["getproduct"])){
        //$ordenar="nome";
        //}
        switch($ordenar){
            case "referencia":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY referencia";
                break;
            case "diametroaco":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY diametroaco";
                break;
            case "comprimentototal":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY comprimentototal";
                break;
            case "diametroexterior":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY diametroexterior";
                break;
            case "passo":
                $ordenar_por="ORDER BY passo";
                break;
        }

        include ("db.php");
        // $molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp";
           //$molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp $ordenar_por";
        $molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp WHERE (diametroaco BETWEEN '$d1' and '$d2') AND (comprimentototal BETWEEN '$comp1' AND '$comp2') AND (diametroexterior BETWEEN '$de1' AND '$de2') $ordenar_por";

        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$molcomp_query);
        // var_dump($run_query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                $id_mol_comp=$row['id_mol_comp'];
                $referencia=$row['referencia'];
                $diametroaco=$row['diametroaco'];
                $comprimentototal=$row['comprimentototal'];
                $diametroexterior=$row['diametroexterior'];
                $passo=$row['passo'];
                $preco=$row['preco'];
                echo
                "<div class='card mx-auto w-100'>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                            <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-md-1'>$referencia</div>
                            <div class='col-md-2'>$diametroaco</div>
                            <div class='col-md-2'>$comprimentototal</div>
                            <div class='col-md-2'>$diametroexterior</div>
                            <div class='col-md-1'>$passo</div>
                            <div class='col-md-1'>$preco</div>
                            <div class='col-md-1'><i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf1c1;</i> <i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf217;</i> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>";
           }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estes erros(grande parte) estão ocorrendo, pois o método da requisição não é o mesmo que está no `if`:

```
if( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) ){
```

Provavelmente você esteja acessando a página diretamente e não por submeter um formulário.

Eis que seu código contém os indexes todos dentro do `if` que exige que o método da requisição seja `POST` e tão logo que o método seja `GET` os indexes estarão todos indefinidos.

Aqui você tem **duas opções**:

**1** - Definir os indexes previamente(antes do `if`) e se caso a requisição fosse com o método `POST` redefiniria os mesmos, providenciando outras correções e validações que são necessárias, ou;

**2** - Trazer todo o código que depende destes indexes para dentro do bloco do `if` que é processado quando o método é `POST`.

Um exemplo, utilizando a opção 2:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) ){
    if ($_POST["d1"]<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["d1"];
    }else{
        $d1="0,200";
    }
    if ($_POST["d2"]<>""){
        $d2=$_POST["d2"];
    }else{
        $d2="20";
    }
    if ($_POST["comp1"]<>""){
        $comp1=$_POST["comp1"];
    }else{
        $comp1="1";
    } 
    if ($_POST["comp2"]<>""){
        $comp2=$_POST["comp2"];
    }else{
        $comp2="10000";
    } 
    if ($_POST["de1"]<>""){
        $de1=$_POST["de1"];
    }else{
        $de1="1";
    }
    if ($_POST["de2"]<>""){
        $de2=$_POST["de2"];
    }else{
        $de2="200";
    }
    $ordenar = $_POST["ordenar"];

    //if(isset($_POST["getproduct"])){ 
    //$ordenar="nome"; 
    //} 
    switch($ordenar){ 
        case "referencia": 
            $ordenar_por="order by referencia"; 
        break; 
        case "diametroaco": 
            $ordenar_por="order by diametroaco"; 
        break; 
        case "comprimentototal": 
            $ordenar_por="order by comprimentototal"; 
        break; 
        case "diametroexterior": 
            $ordenar_por="order by diametroexterior"; 
        break; 
        case "passo": 
            $ordenar_por="order by passo"; 
        break; 
    } 

    include ("db.php"); 
    // $molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp"; 
       //$molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp $ordenar_por"; 
    $molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp WHERE (diametroaco BETWEEN '$d1' and '$d2') AND (comprimentototal BETWEEN '$comp1' AND '$comp2') AND (diametroexterior BETWEEN '$de1' AND '$de2') $ordenar_por"; 

    $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$molcomp_query); 
             var_dump($run_query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($run_query) > 0){ 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){ 
            $id_mol_comp=$row['id_mol_comp']; 
            $referencia=$row['referencia']; 
            $diametroaco=$row['diametroaco']; 
            $comprimentototal=$row['comprimentototal']; 
            $diametroexterior=$row['diametroexterior']; 
            $passo=$row['passo']; 
            $preco=$row['preco']; 
            echo" 
            <div class='card mx-auto w-100'> 
            <div class='card-body'> 
            <div class='row'> 
            <div class='col-md-1'>$referencia</div> 
            <div class='col-md-2'>$diametroaco</div> 
            <div class='col-md-2'>$comprimentototal</div> 
            <div class='col-md-2'>$diametroexterior</div> 
            <div class='col-md-1'>$passo</div> 
            <div class='col-md-1'>$preco</div> 
            <div class='col-md-1'><i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf1c1;</i> <i style='font-size:30px' class='fa'>&#xf217;</i> </div> 
            </div> 
            </div> 
            </div> 
            <br>"; 
        } 
    }   
}
?>
```